# Shellscript send a message to a socket and keep connection alive

Tags: shell

I'm quite new to shell scripting and my issue is I'm not really sure how to make my socket connections alive. 
I'm not sure whether the script that I have written is doing what it is supposed to do.

What I try to do is, I believe I create 140 sockets and send a message to these sockets and I want these socket connections to be kept alive.

```
for (( i=0; i<140; i++))
do
echo "Message" > /dev/tcp/187.98.06.01/4599
done
```

There is a server to which I send this message, I also get a log message that client connection is established in the server end, but when I check the number of socket connections, the number is 0. I'm not sure whether it is because the socket connections are getting closed.

I need to keep the socket connection alive. 
Could anyone provide a suggestion or fix for the above code.

Answer (score 2):

> I use GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

This is not terribly safe *and* not terribly portable, but you *should* be able to write:

```
# Open 140 TCP connections to port 4599 on 187.98.06.01, using
# file-descriptors 60 through 199:
for (( i = 0 ; i < 140 ; i++ )) ; do
    fd=$((i + 60))
    eval exec "$fd<>/dev/tcp/187.98.06.01/4599"
    echo Message >&$fd
done

# ... do whatever you want with these 140 connections ...

# Close the connections:
for (( i = 0 ; i < 140 ; i++ )) ; do
    fd=$((i + 60))
    eval exec "$fd<&-" "$fd>&-"
done
```

(The reason it's not portable is that it depends on Bash features that aren't shared by all shells. The reason it's not safe is that the shell uses file-descriptors for its own internal stuff, e.g. opening scripts and searching directories. Descriptors 0 through 9 — STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, and seven others — are intended for your use, but descriptors 10 and higher risk conflicting with what the shell is doing. In Bash 4.x there's a feature that lets you provide a variable-name to the redirection and let Bash decide what file-descriptor to use, but Bash 3.x doesn't have that.)